# Consulta de los Fragment

Tags: android-studio

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, les informó que sigo avanzando con mi proyecto, ahora estoy aprendiendo a manejar los fragment, actualmente tengo la pantalla y los cuatro fragment, ya están con los diseños y me dispongo a realizar la codificación en java, pero me asaltaron alguna dudas.
este es el fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".Controlador.policial">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="100"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtunidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/unidad"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtconstancia"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/constancia"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtparte"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/parte"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="100"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtestamento"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/estamento"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="60"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtcausa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/causa"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtfechaparte"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/fecha4"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtfechacitacion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/fecha5"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ahora esto es lo que quiero hacer como siempre se hace en java para empezar a trabajar con los edittext, donde los declaro, estuve averiguando y realice este proceso en java en comparación con lo del día de ayer ya declare, ahora tengo problemas con el código para las fechas y otras cosas que se realizan en un formulario normal (activity en java) como son los public y otros procesos este es el código en java.

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.prueba1.R;

public policial() {

}
private EditText et_unidad,et_constancia,et_parte,et_estamento,et_causa,et_fecha,et_fecha1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_policial, container, false);
    et_unidad = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtunidad);
    et_constancia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtconstancia);
    et_parte = view.findViewById(R.id.txtparte);
    et_estamento = view.findViewById(R.id.txtestamento);
    et_causa = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcausa);
    et_fecha = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechaparte);
    et_fecha1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechacitacion);

    et_fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    fragment_policial.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    et_fecha.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    et_fecha1.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

ojala que me puedan ayudar con mis dudas que poseo, ya que quiero seguir aprendiendo y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu preguntas esta relacionada a como y donde obtener las referencias de las vistas, estas se obtienen dentro del método `onCreateView()` en el caso de un `Fragment`, aquí mismo, al obtener las referencias puedes definir los listener:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_policial, container, false);
    et_unidad = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtunidad);
    et_constancia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtconstancia);
    et_parte = view.findViewById(R.id.txtparte);
    et_estamento = view.findViewById(R.id.txtestamento);
    et_causa = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcausa);
    et_fecha = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechaparte);
    et_fecha1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechacitacion);

   //*Asigna listener a et_fecha.      
   et_fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
             //*Realiza tarea.
    });

 return view;

}
```

pero **es muy importante que todas estas vistas se encuentren dentro del layout que "inflas", en este caso se deben encontrar dentro de `fragment_policial.xml`**

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda como siempre, ahora lo otro con el código del et_fecha me envía este error "'DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context, android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int)' in 'android.app.DatePickerDialog' cannot be applied to '(com.example.prueba1.Controlador.policial, anonymous android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int)'", no sé en donde me equivoco, ya que este código para la fecha lo realizo con las actividades normales y con el fragment me da problemas no lo sé, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @Hector este es otro error diferente, podrías agregar otra pregunta para esto, pero si el código es el de tu pregunta en realidad es el contexto, al crear el DatePickerDialog, en lugar de fragment_policial.this usa getActivity()